# Tweet content is truncated when is loaded via twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to download posts from Twitter using twitteR with following code:

```
library(twitteR)

consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."
access_token = '...'
access_secret = '...'

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

u = getUser('realDonaldTrump')
tl = userTimeline(u, n = 3200)
d = twListToDF(tl)
```

Tweets downloaded this way are truncated. For example:
[image: t.co/UxBD2DBv2G]
is downloaded as: `Can’t wait to be back in the amazing state of Tennessee to address the 99th American @FarmBureau Federation’s Annua…`.

Is is possible to download whole tweets contents?

Answer (score 1):

Add the tweet_mode=extended parameter to your API call.

Comment: Easier said than done. The interest of such a package is actually not to bother with the proper API calls. The `userTimeline` function provides a `...` argument that is supposed to transfer supplementary parameter to the Twitter API but in my experience, it does not work: `Error in tw_from_response(out, ...) : 
  unused argument (tweet_mode = "extended")`

Comment: Sounds like something to raise with the original author(s) of the package, then.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation regarding twitter entities.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object